# OAuthException - #200 #200 Permissions error POSTing comment to open graph object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, graph, oauth, comments

I am trying to publish a comment to an open graph object based on the documentation found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

I get an OAuth exception when attempting to POST to this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/139202939585805/comments where 139202939585805 is the object ID of my Open Graph object which you can look up using the Graph API explorer and FQL:

```
SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url = "smaxsport.com/Object/GetNation/2222/"
```

I have attempted post a comment to this object using every available permission in the API explorer.

What am I missing?

Update: I switched the object URL to all lower case can I got a different (correct) object ID. Now when I attempt to post using the new id 506612756058150 I get:

```
(OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred.
```

Update2:

Here is the code I am using via the c# fb SDK

```
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "test message";
        var result = await _fb.PostTaskAsync(https://graph.facebook.com/506612756058150/comments", parameters);
```

The user is signed and I am using a valid access token. I've also tried this using the Graph Explorer.

Comment: Show us your code. How are you posting the comment?

Comment: Added to post under "Update2"

Comment: Thanks for taking a look!